# Option list not working properly in Safari, Mozila, Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, firefox, safari

I ran into some problems while maiking a front-end of my webapp. There a few problmes:

1. I need to cut text if too long, so I do

   > .suggestion-box-text {   white-space: nowrap;   overflow: hidden;
   > text-overflow: ellipsis; }

But then I can't use scroll in Chrome, only keys.
2. No matter what I use to Safari remembers the last selected item from list, and next time when using selection it starts from it, not from the first element.

3. And also nothing works properly in FireFox, when do the same thing to cut too long text, scroll still works, but when I move with keys, the list doesn't scroll.

   Is there any known way to fix this? Or just try try and good luck until you find a working combination?

HTML FILE

```
<div class="navbar-container container-fluid">
        <div class="" id="site-navbar-search">
            <form id="originalSearch" role="search" ng-submit="query()">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px">
                    <div class="input-search">
                        <speech class=""></speech>

                        <input id="questionForInput" type="text"
                          ng-change="ask.getsuggestions()" autocomplete="off"
                          ng-model="ask.term" class="form-control bg-dark"
                          placeholder="Ask ..." ng-keydown="key($event)"/>

                        <select id="suggestionSelection" class="suggestion-box
                          list-group2 bg-dark" ng-keydown="key2($event)"
                          multiple="multiple"ng-model="ask.term">

                          <option class="list-group-item2 suggestion-box-text bg-dark"
                            ng-repeat="command in ask.suggestions">
                              {{command.statement}}
                          </option>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" style="visibility: hidden; display:none"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS FILE

```
.suggestion-box {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 18px 18px;
  outline: none;
}

.suggestion-box-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

@supports (overflow:-webkit-marquee) and (justify-content:inherit)
{
  .suggestion-box {
      padding-left: 15px;
  }
}


body{
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-base-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: black;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #C0C0C0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px; height: 0px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {  background-color: #666; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  background-color: #999;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece { background-color: #ffffff;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { height: 0px; background-color: #666; border-radius: 0px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner { background-color: #999;}}
::-webkit-resizer { background-color: #666;}
```

Also part of JS file

```
$scope.key = function($event){
          if ($event.keyCode == 40) {
            $('#suggestionSelection').focus();
            $('#suggestionSelection').focus();
            //$("select#suggestionSelection").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
            //$("#suggestionSelection")[0].selectedIndex = -1;
          }
          else if($event.keyCode == 27) {
            $('#suggestionSelection').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#questionForInput').css('border-radius', '200px 200px 200px 200px');
          }
        }

        $scope.key2 = function($event){
          console.log($event.keyCode);
          if ($event.keyCode == 38) {
            if($('#suggestionSelection')[0].selectedIndex == -1 || $('#suggestionSelection')[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
              $('#questionForInput').focus();
              $('#suggestionSelection').css('visibility', 'hidden');
              $('#questionForInput').css('border-radius', '200px 200px 200px 200px');
            }
          }
          else if($event.keyCode == 27 || $event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#questionForInput').focus();
            $('#suggestionSelection').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#questionForInput').css('border-radius', '200px 200px 200px 200px');


          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use ngOptions directive (it is much faster than ng-repeat on `<option>`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions